# how to connectASIHTTPRequest for WebService

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am new to iphone....when i need to connect to one of the web service i am using follwing code tat is using ASIHTTP request..when i add this code its coming error

ASIHTTPRequest is undeclared declare it first where i shd declare and wat i shd declare?i am using UIViewController class

how i shd declare? wat i shd do?plz suggest me
the code is given below

```
-(void)callWebService

{

   //this is a typical url for REST webservice, where you can specify the method that you want to call and the parameters directly with GET

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourserver.net/webservice/rest/?method=myMethod&par1=ok"];

   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

   [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestCompleted:)];

   [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestError:)];

   [request setDelegate:self];

   [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestCompleted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

}

- (void)requestError:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

   NSError *error = [request error];

}
```

thank u...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check that you have asihttp package attached in your project.
After that check you have

`#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"` import this in your viewcontroller

Dont forget to check that you have attached the following frameworks. CFNetwork, SystemConfiguration, MobileCoreServices, CoreGraphics and libz framework.

You have not tell which method to use

```
[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"]; BEFORE  [request startAsynchronous];
```

When you will right click on framework folder this popup will appear.
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Abhilash on frameworks folder right click select on add existing frameworks a pop up will displayed there you will get it.

Comment: thank u ...how to add ashihttp package? and also where this MobileCoreServices and libz framework located iam not getting it

Comment: @Abhilash you have download asihttppackage from net and add files in your project.

Comment: @Abhhilash you can download it from this link https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree

Comment: and also there in so such option in my xcode when i right click

Comment: @abhilash see my edited answer I have attached snapshots how to do it.

Comment: Thanks alot for ur answer but mine is xcode 4.0.1 in tat there is only options like  new file, new project,add  file to "project name"

Comment: i added system config and CFNetwork but iam not gettign mobilecoreservices i searched in developer/sdkd/system in tat folder as wel

Comment: ok might be 4.0.2 works with these only.Now try to run you code  .dont forget to add these lines #import "ASIHTTPRequest.h" and [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"]; BEFORE  [request startAsynchronous];

Comment: no still iam having errors like request undeclared use it in function first

Comment: yeh because you have not installed all frameworks.see more I think you have missed something.See more to add freamewok you will get these also.I am using xcode version 3.2.5 and ios 4.2

Comment: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jenesys/Documents/WebSample1/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIHTTPRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WebSample1ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: you have to check out why you are not getting these fameworks.They are needed to implement your code.

Comment: thank u i got all the frameworks only prob facing is importing zlib file..i am not getting path..

Comment: dats grt all the best and happy coding.